# Watir-webdriver timing out when asked if element is present?

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver

- Ruby 1.9.3p327
- watir-webdriver 0.6.1

On a fresh Ruby install, with a fresh webdriver install, I am unable to use wait or present? with nonpresent elements without causing non-Watir Timeout errors.

In the below example, id 'gb_32' is on the page, but hidden. Id 'gb_50000' does not exist. In both cases "present?" should return false, but the second one gives me a timeout error after 60 seconds.
Any ideas why this could happen?

```
    irb(main):014:0> b.link(:id,'gb_32').present?
    => false
    irb(main):015:0> b.link(:id,'gb_50000').present?
    Timeout::Error: Timeout::Error
            from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:146:in `rescue in rbuf_fill'
            from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:140:in `rbuf_fill'
            from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:122:in `readuntil'
            from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:132:in `readline'
            from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:2562:in `read_status_line'
            from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:2551:in `read_new'
            from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1319:in `block in transport_request'
            from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1316:in `catch'
            from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1316:in `transport_request'
            from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1293:in `request'
            from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1286:in `block in request'
            from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:745:in `start'
            from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1284:in `request'
            from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.25.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:82:in `response_for'
            from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.25.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:38:in `request'
            from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.25.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:40:in `call'
            from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.25.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:598:in `raw_execute'
            from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.25.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:576:in `execute'
            from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.25.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:544:in `find_element_by'
            from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.25.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/search_context.rb:42:in `find_element'
            from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-webdriver-0.6.1/lib/watir-webdriver/locators/element_locator.rb:247:in `by_id'
            from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-webdriver-0.6.1/lib/watir-webdriver/locators/element_locator.rb:26:in `locate'
            from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-webdriver-0.6.1/lib/watir-webdriver/elements/element.rb:384:in `locate'
            from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-webdriver-0.6.1/lib/watir-webdriver/elements/element.rb:362:in `assert_exists'
            from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-webdriver-0.6.1/lib/watir-webdriver/elements/element.rb:37:in `exists?'
            from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-webdriver-0.6.1/lib/watir-webdriver/elements/element.rb:296:in `present?'
    from (irb):15
```

Thanks.

Comment: I managed to put together a kludge for now by using explicit timeouts in the "present?" and "until" methods. Something like this:

`Timeout::timeout(input_timeout=1) do;
#Default webdriver command here;
end;
rescue Timeout::Error;
raise TimeoutError;
end`

Comment: Can you share link to the page or relevant HTML?

Comment: I think it's down to the network driver. The page I was looking at was "www.google.com". The fault still appears on "about:blank" when I try looking for exists? or present? for nonpresent elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd add this as a comment but evidently I can't yet.  Are you using Firefox 17?  Watir-webdriver isn't yet compatible with 17, so if you are then try reverting to Firefox 16 and see if your code works.  I understand that a watir-webdriver update to resolve this compatibility issue is being released next week.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I've completely reinstalled Windows and that seems to have fixed this particular issue. I believe it was some sort of spyware / malware side-effect from a previous user of the laptop.

Comment: Yeah that particular error text that does not say something like WHAT it was trying to do when it timed out (like waiting for an element) seems to be indicative of timeouts when webdriver itself is trying to talk to the browser..  the issue is way back there.  not in your code or on a webpage.. it is the communication between webdriver and browser that is getting the timeout